# How to convert a Blob to an image and show it Angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm trying to show an image that have been send from the server side , the server send an image then it convert to a blob but i couldn't convert it to an image to show it in the DOM

This is the code in the `component.ts`

```
getImageFromService() {
      this.authService.getProfileImage().subscribe(data => {
        this.createImageFromBlob(data);
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

this code get the image from the server as a blob

This is the code i write to convert the blob to an image

```
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        this.imageToShow = reader.result;
     }, false);

     if (image) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);
     }
  }
```

This the code in the HTML

```
<img [src]="imageToShow " alt="" class="img">
```

This is the Response in chrome devtool

```
Blob(763750) {size: 763750, type: "text/xml"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only have to do this to convert from Blob to file:

```
const file = new File([blob], fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering a bit late but here is a solution:

**TS**:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

img;

constructor(private storageService: StorageService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

this.storageService.downloadBlob("myImage").subscribe(blob => {
     const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     const img = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
     this.img = img;
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<img [src]="img"/>
```

Learn more about `createObjectURL`: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

And `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Answer (score -2):

I tried this, and works for my:

In `component.ts`

```
imageToShow : any;
getImageFromService() {
      this.authService.getProfileImage().subscribe(data => {
        this.imageToShow = data;
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

In the HTML

```
<img [src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageToShow" alt="" class="img">
```

so late, but I hope help you